# Как изменить иконку кластера, чтобы она не сбрасывалась при зуме карты?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть задача менять иконку кластера при клике, есть такой код для этого:

```
clusterer.events.add("click", function (e) {

var cluster = e.get('target');



var icons = [{

    "href": "/img/point1.png",

    "size": [88, 27],

    "offset": [-50, -50]

}];

cluster.options.unset('icons');

cluster.options.set('icons', icons);
});
```

Он работает, но при зуме (который при клике сразу и происходит), иконка сбрасывается на исходную. Как правильно сделать, чтобы кластер сохранял вторую иконку?

Версия карт 2.1.

Comment: Опишите подробнее какого поведения вы пытаетесь добиться. Кластеры пересоздают при зуме, так что иконка не сбрасывается - это просто другой кластер.

Comment: Поведения, чтобы кластер, по которому был клик, изменял иконку (как посещенная в браузере ссылка) и сохранял ее при зуме.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При зуме кластера перерасчитываются: старые удаляются и создаются новые. Визуально находящиеся на одном месте `ClusterPlacemark`'и до и после зума - разные гео-объекты.

Если говорить о кластерах состоящих одинаковых гео-объектов, то можно переопределить [`Clusterer.createCluster`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Clusterer-docpage/#createCluster) и при создании нового кластера проверять не было ли клика по кластеру из тех же гео-объектов до этого. Для генерации уникальных идентифиторов гео-объектов можно использовать [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) из ES2015. Для IE младше 11 версии и прочих старых браузеров вы можете использовать [полифилл](https://github.com/polygonplanet/weakmap-polyfill).

```js
ymaps.ready([
  'Map', 'Placemark', 'Clusterer', 'ClusterPlacemark'
]).then(function() {
  var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.75, 37.62], zoom: 9, controls: []
  });
  var placemarks = [
    new ymaps.Placemark([55.75, 37.62]),
    new ymaps.Placemark([55.75, 37.52]),
    new ymaps.Placemark([55.75, 37.72]),
  ];
  
  var clusterer = createVisitedClusterer({
    // Опции кластеризатора.
    clusterIconColor: 'black'
  }, {
    // Опции "посещенных" кластеров.
    iconColor: 'red'
  });
  clusterer.add(placemarks);

  map.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
}).catch(console.error);

function createVisitedClusterer(options, visitedClusterOptions) {
  // Создаем кластеризатор.
  var clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer(options);
  
  // Сохраняем старую функцию createCluster с помощью Function.prototype.bind.
  var defaultCreateCluster = clusterer.createCluster.bind(clusterer);
  
  // Хеш посещенных кластеров.
  var visitedClusters = { /* 'id,id,id': true */ };
  
  // Переопределяем метод createCluster у кластеризатора.
  clusterer.createCluster = function(center, geoObjects) {
    // Создаем стандартный кластер.
    var cluster = defaultCreateCluster(center, geoObjects);
    
    // Собираем уникальные идентификаторы для объектов кнутри кластера.
    var ids = geoObjects.map(function(x) { return getUniqueId(x); });
    ids.sort(function(lhs, rhs) { return lhs - rhs; });
    
    // Собираем уникальный идентификатор кластера.
    var clusterId = ids.join(',');
    
    if (visitedClusters[clusterId]) {
      // Если кластер был посещен ранее, сразу применяем опции.
      cluster.options.set(visitedClusterOptions);
    } else {
      cluster.events.add('click', function() {
        // Помечаем кластер как посещенный при клике.
        visitedClusters[clusterId] = true;

        // Применяем опции, на случай зум по клику выключен,
        // или зум уже максимальный.
        cluster.options.set(visitedClusterOptions);
      });
    }

    return cluster;
  };

  return clusterer;
}

// Генерация уникальных идентификаторов.
var uniqueIds = new WeakMap();
var lastUniqueId = 0;
function getUniqueId(geoObject) {
  if (!uniqueIds.has(geoObject)) {
    uniqueIds.set(geoObject, lastUniqueId++);
  }
  return uniqueIds.get(geoObject);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 300px"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за полностью рабочий пример.
Но возникает проблема, если я задаю следующие опции в качестве изначальных: https://jsfiddle.net/hg78qmz1/
Ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined.
Хотя в изначальном варианте такие настройки работали.

Comment: Если убрать clusterIcons, то вроде работает, но мне нужно менять кастомную иконку, а не стандартную.

Comment: Всё, разобрался. Нужно указывать массив иконок, а не 1 объект. Странно, что работало изначально. Ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: Код действительно рабочий. Вставил - и все заработало. Правда я лузер в этих вопросах. А как будет выглядеть этот же код без настроек цветов кластеров (стандартный синий яндекс) и чтобы можно было поменять на свою иконку кластера - как в гугле красивую такую.